# TF Build 2010 trying to access my System32 directory

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I have TF Build 2010 running. I gave the "VS Team Foundation Build Service Host" service admin privileges on the machine (for testing purpose).

I am using the default build template unmodified and I have a simple straight forward solution (no pre nor post build stuff and no unit or integration test). The solution is a mix of .NET 4.5 and C++/CLI projects.

Everytime I build, the build reports "half success" because it failed to access some directory on C:\Windows\system32[some directory]

1. If I set explicitly on this directory that the service
   account (the account in which the Build service is running under)
   has admin privileges (for testing) to this folder, the problem still
   exist.
2. If I delete the directory from system32 (for testing again!), TF Build will report another directory within system32.
3. Rebooting the machine did not help.

1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config' is denied.

**I am not sure why TF Build 2010 is trying to access the system32 as the log is not helping and I am not sure why when it has local admin privileges it is still giving access denied.**

Some log is below:

```
For Each TestSpec in TestSpecs
Initial Property Values
Values = Run tests in assemblies matching **\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll

00:00
Try Run Tests

00:00
Run MSTest for Test Assemblies

00:00
Assign spec to testAssembly
Initial Property Values
Value = Run tests in assemblies matching **\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll
Final Property Values
To = Run tests in assemblies matching **\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll
Value = Run tests in assemblies matching **\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll

00:00
Find Test Assemblies
Initial Property Values
MatchPattern = D:\Builds\2\Applications\Main Build\Binaries\**\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll
There were no matches for the search pattern D:\Builds\2\Applications\Main Build\Binaries\**\*.Test.Unit.dll
Final Property Values
MatchPattern = D:\Builds\2\Applications\Main Build\Binaries\**\*.Test.Unit.dll;**\*.Test.Integration.dll
Result = 

00:00
Handle MSTest Exception

00:00
If testException is NOT TestFailureException
Initial Property Values
Condition = True
 Access to the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\config' is denied.
Final Property Values
Condition = True
```

Comment: Set the MSBUILD to verbose and put relevant part of the  actual log here please.

Comment: If you set the Build Def to Disable Tests, does the build work then?